Resource assignment between specific period
I'm calculating resource allocation in a month. Each row represent person's allocation.
I'm using 2019 excel version so XLOOKUP cannot be used.
Calculations:
Header has Allocation Start Date and End Date, followed by different months (say M1, M2, M3 and so on). Here M1 is 01-Jul-24, M2 is 01-Aug-24, M3 is 01-Sep-24, etc.
Allocation calculations: Number of allocations days (work days) Divided by Number of Total Work Days in that month. For 1st row since the allocation is only for 5 days in M3 (Sep-24) then Allocation would be 5 Divide by 21 = 0.24



Start
End
07/01/24
08/01/24
09/01/24
10/01/24
11/01/24
12/01/24




09/02/24
09/06/24
0.00
0.00
0.24
0.00
0.00
0.00


07/01/24
10/15/24
1.00
1.00
1.00
0.48
0.00
0.00


11/01/24
12/21/24
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
1.00
0.68



Any help is appreciated

I added a 01/01/2025 in column I.
Formula in C2 is this:
=IF(OR($A2>D$1-1,$B2<C$1),0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX($A2,C$1),MIN($B2,D$1-1),1,)/NETWORKDAYS.INTL(C$1,D$1-1,1,))

If startDate > MonthEnd, or endDate < MonthStart, allocation = 0;
otherwise, we use MAX(startDate, MonthStart) as "effective start date", MIN(endDate, MonthEnd) as "effective end date".
You can fill it to the right, then fill it down.


The excel version that i uses is 2019 and it looks like LET doesnt work on this version. I'm getting #NAME? error

At least NETWORKDAYS.INTL is supported in 2019. Will remove let.

@AmritpalSingh, I removed let. Also you don't need XLOOKUP to check wether "start, end" overlaps with a given month or not, you just need to check start <=MonthEnd and end >=MonthStart.

Thank you Rachel. This worked. Really appreciate your help.
